# Configuring HTTPS without passing by Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a way to configure SSL with my static website on S3 without passing by Cloudfront or with a lower cost than 20$ per Day.

Thanks

Comment: <offtopic> Maybe you should think about to monetize your website if your traffic is so high that you generate 20$ costs per day with CloudFront :-D </offtopic>

Comment: Where are you getting the $20 per day calculation for costs of Cloudfront?

Comment: Unless you are serving millions of requests per day, CloudFront is not costing you $20 **more** than it would cost to run your site without it.  Using CloudFront typically reduces your S3 bill by about as much as CloudFront itself costs.

Comment: You pay $600 per month for each custom SSL certificate associated with one or more CloudFront distributions.